# Making backup with Git in android studio

Tags: android, git, backup

I'm working on a Calculator app. at the current state app works fine but I want to try a different approach which requires make drastic changes to my codes. I want to make a backup copy of my project and from what i heard Git is a good solution. So I installed Git and activate it in Android Studio. But I'm new in coding and do not understand Git or its linguistics. What I want is to be able to have complete backup of current state or version of my app before changing things and later be able to go back and forth between versions easily. It would be great if someone could help me with it? or knows a tutorial site or some videos which clearly explains things about Version Control and Git.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/

Comment: here is good course from [udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/version-control-with-git--ud123)